# Proporciones height_ratio con gridspec

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Estaba interesado en cambiar las dimensiones de un plot usando el modulo `gridspec` de `matplotlib`. El siguiente codigo muestra 3 plots. Los dos primeros (rojo y azul) estan anidados debido a `gs1`, y el tercero "libre" como `gs2`.
Se que con `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)` puedo cambiar la distancia entre los dos primero plots a 0.
Sin embargo, me gustaria cambiar el ratio entre ellos. Por ejemplo, que el plot2 (azul) tenga una altura de 0.25 respecto al Plot1 (rojo), manteniendo la distancia entre ellos = 0, y una distancia de por ejemplo 0.3 con el Plot3 (verde). Intuyo que tiene que estar relacionado con `plt.subplots_adjust` pero no consigo obtenerla figura deseada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np


t  = np.arange(50)
y1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 50)
y2 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 50)
y3 = np.random.randint(0, 20, 50)

gs_gen = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[1, 1], hspace=0.3) 
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec=gs_gen[0])
gs2 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1, subplot_spec=gs_gen[1])

fig=plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1, 0], sharex=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs2[0, 0])

ax1.plot(t, y1, color='red', label='Plot1')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_xlabel('tiempo [s]')
ax1.set_ylabel('ax1')
ax1.legend(loc='best')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', labelbottom=False)

ax2.plot(t, y2, color='blue', label='Plot2')
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_xlabel('tiempo [s]')
ax2.set_ylabel('ax2')
ax2.legend(loc='best')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', labelbottom=True)

ax3.plot(t, y3, color = 'green', label='Plot3')
ax3.grid(True)
ax3.set_xlabel('tiempo [s]')
ax3.set_ylabel('ax3')
ax3.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)
plt.show()
```

Alguna idea de como llevar a cabo esta accion ya sea con `gridspec` o `subplots`?.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Dimas no me equivoco las dimensiones dependen de los valores de X y Y, pero no se si te refieres a eso o a escalar el gráfico

Comment: Me refiero a escalar el gráfico Plot2. Los valores máximos y mínimos vienen dados por los propios datos. Sería como estrechar el Plot2. O bien cambiar el height_ratio